# How to save data from a table from another database in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to save data from an order table from one database to another through Laravel. I created a function in my controller like this:

```
public function getMarketplace()
{
    $orderoc = OrderOC::orderBy('oc_order.date_added', 'desc')
                        ->join('oc_order_product', 'oc_order_product.order_id', 'oc_order.order_id')
                        ->join('oc_order_history', 'oc_order_history.order_id', 'oc_order.order_id')
                        ->where('oc_order_history.order_status_id', '=', '17')
                        ->get();

    foreach($orderoc as $oc){

        $ordererp = new Order;
        $ordererp->erp_createdid = $oc->created_id;
        $ordererp->erp_marketplaceid = 1;
        $ordererp->erp_site = rand(1,100000000);
        $ordererp->erp_payment_method = $oc->payment_method;
        $ordererp->erp_orderdate = $oc->date_added;
        $ordererp->erp_orderaprove = $oc->date_added;
        $ordererp->erp_billingid = 1;
        $ordererp->erp_shippingid = 1;
        $ordererp->erp_marketplace = 'Comércio Urbano';
        $ordererp->erp_orderquantity = $oc->quantity;
        $ordererp->erp_erro = '';
        $ordererp->erp_product_ok = 1;
        $ordererp->erp_compraId = null;
        $ordererp->save();

        if(strlen($oc->created_id) == 0){
            $oc->created_id = rand(1,10000000);
            $oc->save();
        }

        $orderprod = new OrderProduct;
        $orderprod->erp_productid = $oc->product_id;
        $orderprod->erp_createdid = $oc->created_id;
        $orderprod->erp_model = $oc->model;
        $orderprod->erp_quantity = $oc->quantity;
    }
}
```

One table is from my ERP and the other is responsible for receiving OpenCart purchases, but every time I run, the same product appears more than once in my order table.
(It is possible to see through the purchase date, since created_id is created in the controller function)

Does anyone know how to tell me why data is duplicated when inserted inside a foreach? This is not the first time, if you tell me a more robust way of doing the job, I'm grateful. Any suggestion? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have you double check maybe `$orderoc` has duplicated datas? try `dd($orderoc)` and check again.

Comment: You can use `groupBy` or `unique` on Table to avoid duplicate entries from join

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity is you put `unique` validation on a table that receive the data

Comment: So I thought about that, but since created_id is being generated inside the foreach, it is possible that it is regenerated, with the same characteristics, I would like OpenCart to provide some ID to facilitate these implementations. Anyway, I'll try to put it in a separate table, I believe it works better. (Aliás, sou paranaense também)